# Add Active Class Based on Segment?

Tags: javascript, jquery, substring

I have URLs in my nav that I am trying to target to add an active class based on the first segment and not the absolute URL but it is not working.

> /* Get URL For Setting Active Nav List Item */
>
> var url =  window.location.pathname.split( '/' ),
>
> path = url[2];

```
$(".navbar-nav").children("li").each(function() {
    var link = $(this).children("a").attr("href"),
        linkPathIndex = link.lastIndexOf("/")+1,
        linkPath = link.substring(linkPathIndex);

    if (linkPath == path) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

HTML

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="www.example.com/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="www.example.com/products">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="www.example.com/services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="www.example.com/about-us">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm trying to have it apply my active class to the navbar even if the url structure is as such:

about-us
about-us/locations
about-us/employment

If about-us is within the first segment it should apply the active class.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? I appreciate any and all feedback.

Comment: Add a `console.log(linkPath, path)` and check what comes out.

Comment: @steven added path above. Thanks!

Comment: @AoiHana Links like `www.example.com/about-us` won't work well; either use `//www.example.com/about-us` or `/about-us`. Moreover, if being in `http://www.example.com/about-us`, `location.pathname.split('/')[2]` will be `undefined`; if you want `'about-us'`, use `path = url[1]`